# Off-canvas mobile navigation with minimal side effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

### Problem

I'm looking for a JS (jQuery) library which provides off-canvas navigation for mobile devices, with native-like UX, **minimal influence** to existing page and compatible acros many mobile browsers (FF, Chrome, Android default, Dolphin, iOS, ...). It should be as lightweight as possible.

### Motivation

Script providing a common JS menu for about 50 different sites. The only way I can influence their HTML is by using JS (admins of these sites adds just `<script src="http://somewhere_else.xx/...`). When I do big manipulations with their existing HTML, I run into compatibility issues.

### Solutions I've tried

- [Snap.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js) (too much DOM manipulation needed)
- [Overthrow](https://github.com/filamentgroup/Overthrow) (bad compatibility)

Comment: Nicely formulated question, but on SO asking for a library/tool/plugin etc. is unfortunately considered off-topic.. We'd love to see more code specification in this matter!

Answer (score 2):

check out these, and give a try. you may find them easy and compatible.

```
http://christopheryee.ca/pushy/

http://www.aidanzealley.com/offcanvas/

http://www.berriart.com/sidr/
```

pure css solution

http://css-tricks.com/off-canvas-menu-with-css-target/